# What does "->" mean in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What exactly does -> do in php?

I have a good understanding of the basics of php but never understood this. I tend to see in apps that use Codeignitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> is accessing a varible inside of a class, so that

$class->variableInClass

It also can work with functions, with the same syntax as above.

If you're not familiar with OOP, I'd suggest looking [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Not a regular user of PHP, but don't you mean object? You would use the `::` operator to access class variables.

Comment: "Variables inside of a class" are actually "properties of an object" ))) And with `->` not only properties can be used.

Answer (score 4):

It accesses accessible child methods or properties of objects:

```
class myClass {
  public $fizz = 'Buzz';
  public function foo() {
    echo 'Bar';
  }
}

$myclass = new myClass();
$myclass->foo(); // outputs 'bar'
$myclass->fizz = 'Not Buzz'; // overwrites $fizz value
```

Comment: the best of understanding it is through an example. Excellent!

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure theres a more technical explanation but that is used to access properties and methods of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Its basically the equivalent to the `.` in javascript.  The both acess an Objects properties/methods.

The biggest difference is that in PHP only `class`es are Objects.  While in JavaScript everything is an Object.

Therefore you can't do `"string"->method()` in php while you can do the equivalent in JavaScript `"string".method()`.

Comment: PERFECT!!! now this i understand! lol good job.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would razz you a bit because this is a very common operator. However it's very difficult to google for, so I understand.

This is a class access operator. It allows you to access members and functions of a class. So for example if I have a class named A with a member x, I could access it like this:

```
$a = new A();
$a->x;
```